# Message service file not found

Tags: catkin-make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am learning ROS recently as the tutorial of ROS wiki.When I use the command `catkin_build install`or `catkin_build`, it output the error:`Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed`.The detailed output is here:

```
ubuntu@tegra-ubuntu:~/catkin_ws$ catkin_make install
Base path: /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/build"
####
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /opt/ros/indigo
-- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/indigo
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/build/test_results
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
-- catkin 0.6.16
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- ~~  traversing 1 packages in topological order:
-- ~~  - beginner_tutorials
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'beginner_tutorials'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(beginner_tutorials)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;genlisp;genpy
CMake Error at /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/assert.cmake:20 (message):


  Assertion failed: file
  '/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/srv/AddTowInts.srv' does not exist.  Message: 
  service file not found

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/indigo/share/genmsg/cmake/genmsg-extras.cmake:167 (assert_file_exists)
  beginner_tutorials/CMakeLists.txt:54 (add_service_files)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
```

**The error files are here:**[link text](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B-OKitZIRELKTER6UGpuWm9ELVU&usp=sharing)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229230/message-service-file-not-found/) by [Fighting_bird](https://answers.ros.org/users/26255/fighting_bird/) on ROS Answers with karma: 72 on 2016-03-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like you've forgotten to create the `AddTwoInts.srv` file, based on this error:

```
Assertion failed: file
'/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/srv/AddTowInts.srv' does not exist.  Message: 
service file not found
```

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2016-03-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Fighting_bird](https://answers.ros.org/users/26255/fighting_bird/) on 2016-03-16**:
Thank you for your reminding! And I just found the error.In fact, the name of the srv file is mistakenly written as 'AddTowInts.srv', but it should be 'AddTwoInts.srv'.